# Return from a recursive for loop

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration

I have written a function to find a number such that the sum of its digits is equal to a given sum and the number of digits equal to a given number. e.g., if given sum = 20 and given no of digits = 3 then the solution is 299 because 299 is the smallest 3 digit number such that the sum of digits of 299 is 20.
Take a look at my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void smallestNumber(int sum, int no_of_digits, int mul, int num, int s_num) {
    int i;

    if(no_of_digits <= 0)
        return;

    for(i=0; i<9; i++) {
        num += (i+1)*mul;
        s_num += (i+1);
        if(s_num == sum) {
            cout << num << endl;
            exit(1);          //Alternative for exit(1)
        } else if(s_num < sum) {
            smallestNumber(sum, no_of_digits-1, mul/10, num, s_num);
        }
        num -= (i+1)*mul;    //Backtracking
        s_num -= (i+1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int sum, no_of_digits;
    cin >> sum >> no_of_digits;
    smallestNumber(sum, no_of_digits, pow(10,no_of_digits-1), 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

In above code I am able to get the solution as required but I can't figure out how to return when s_num=sum. Currently I am using exit(1) here and I can't use return statement as it prints every other combination of number also. Also how can I figure out if the solution is not possible and display -1.

Comment: Whoever told you that you "can't use return statement" is completely wrong. This is the only way to return from a function in C++ (exceptions excepted). End of story. So, if you want to "return" from a function, you have to use the `return` statement. Now, what you need to figure out is how to `return` correctly. Free clue: the problem is not in `return` but what happens after a `return`. You are aware that functions can return stuff. Not just `void`. So, have your function `return` something that tells the caller what the caller needs to do, either `return` itself, or do something else.

Comment: And keep in mind that 1+9+9!=20.

Comment: Also not that you need to have in your function a return or reference otherwise the recursion is pointless

Comment: Corrected it. Thanks

Comment: You really MUST get a better understanding of return. Then you need to make a better explanation to yourself why you are making the recursive call. I see what you're doing, but it could be better if you make it follow a natural language explanation of what you're doing, using good function names. Finally, you probably need the actual function to call a slightly different internal helper (the internal helper is recursive) -- because the logic is slightly different after the first digit, which cannot be zero, but internal digits can.